# How to push message to second kafka cluster topic if first cluster goes down using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have scenario where i need to push message into kafka topic using java....but condition is if my one cluster goes down then need to connect another kafka cluster and push the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to configure two `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` beans and two `KafkaTemplate`s.

When you get an exception, fail over to the other template.

Comment: Probably not related to Ops question. Would it make sense to always check the cluster in the background scheduler task and update the existing factory, template and listener beans to use the cluster which is healthy ? This way we don’t need to maintain two beans. Is it possible ?

Comment: It might work, but you'd have to stop the listener containers, change the broker address on the factories, call `reset()` on the producer factory and re-start the containers; you can't do this with the default factories because they provide no mechanism to change the configuration properties.